# How to save a copy of changed files locally from Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, backup

Basically, I have changed few files in Intellij IDEA and it is 
connected to some version control.

I do not want to commit it to version control, but my objective is 
to keep a copy of these files somewhere in my filesystem.

By doing this,

- I can experiment with the unchanged files in the meantime.
- When I want to restore the changes, I can import these changed files.

A brute force way of doing this is to iterate through list of changed files and
make a copy somewhere. Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Why don't you want to commit it? Why not e.g. work on a branch?

Comment: Don't want to currently involve with version-control system, but want to save changes locally immediately, as it is going to be scrapped out.

Comment: **Why not**. Do you not understand the premise of version control?

Comment: I get it. That's almost like basic purpose of branches - scrap out what is not required and push those into master which contains required changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2017 you can create patches from entire changelists, save to file and then apply from file.

1. Local Changes tab -> right click changelist -> Copy as Patch to Clipboard
2. Paste to .txt file and save.
3. VCS tab -> Apply patch -> select file